# Why won't this code run on load, only on button click?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, onclick, onload-event

I have the following tool. The presets at the bottom are loaded from an XML file. I can't apply the gradients to the presets (labels) on load though, only when a button invokes the code.

See below, on load, and on button click:

[image: CSSGM1]
[image: CSSGM2]

The form is called Main, and the relevant code looks like this:

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stop1.BackColor = Gradient.ForeColor;
    Stop2.BackColor = Gradient.BackColor;
    Populate(Gradient.ForeColor);

    // If XML exists etc snipped
    XmlDoc = XDocument.Load("palette.xml");

    IEnumerable<XElement> cssGM = XmlDoc.Root.Elements();
    Label[] Label = new Label[cssGM.Count()];

    for(int i = 0; i < cssGM.Count(); i++)
    {
        Label[i] = new Label();
        Label[i].Name = "Saved" + i.ToString();
        Label[i].ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(cssGM.ElementAt(i).Elements().ElementAt(0).Elements().ElementAt(1).Value);
        Label[i].BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(cssGM.ElementAt(i).Elements().ElementAt(1).Elements().ElementAt(1).Value);
        Label[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        Label[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(i*54+2, 0);
        Label[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
        SavedPanel.Controls.Add(Label[i]);
        //FillGradient(Label[i]);
        //Label[i].Invalidate();
        //SavedPanel.Refresh();
    }

    FillPalettes();
    //Application.DoEvents();
    //this.Invalidate();
}

public void FillPalettes()
{
    foreach(Label Palette in this.SavedPanel.Controls.OfType<Label>())
    {
        FillGradient(Palette);
    }
}

public void FillGradient(Label Target)
{
    Graphics e = Target.CreateGraphics();
    e.FillRectangle(new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, Target.Height), Target.ForeColor, Target.BackColor), ClientRectangle);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillPalettes();
}
```

I've commented out things I've tried. Also, I know the method of selecting the XML node is fugly... that's something I need to get round to fixing. Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- cssGM - Gradient palette data -->
<cssGM Version="0.3">

  <Gradient name="White to Black">>
    <Stop>
      <Location>0</Location>
      <Colour>#fffffa</Colour>
    </Stop>
    <Stop>
      <Location>100</Location>
      <Colour>#000001</Colour>
    </Stop>
  </Gradient>
  ...
```

Comment: is Main_Load actually hooked to the Load event of the form? (also instead of hooking your own object's events, you could override the OnXXX method instead.)

Comment: @Sahuagin Yes it's hooked up to the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, create your own class that inherits from the standard `Label`:

```
public class GradientLabel : Label {
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, this.Height), this.ForeColor, this.BackColor), ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

Then, it will be drawn constantly. Whenever you change either the `BackColor` or `ForeColor` property of the `GradientLabel`, it will update by itself:

```
gradientLabelInstance.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

Comment: This works perfectly, and it explains in a simple way how I can code moving forwards too. Thanks a lot Simon

Comment: You are welcome :) I would be interested in helping with this little app on behalf of my designer/front end friends if you are looking for it :)

Comment: Thanks for the offer Simon, I'll definitely keep that in mind! I have a lot of ideas of where to go from here. Something bigger than just a little gradient maker ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Form `Loaded` event is fired before the Form is layed out, perhaps all the controls are not ready yet.

You could try using the `Shown` event as all the controls sould be ready by then.

```
    private void Main_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // all your code;
    }
```

as far as I remember from the good'ol winform days is the events are in this order

1. Loaded
2. CreateControl
3. OnActivated
4. Shown
5. OnPaint

and you need to wait for `CreateControl` event to create your `SavedPanel`, so `Shown` event should be fine.

Comment: Using the `Shown` event has the exact same result. Bear in mind, the gradient labels are created programmatically in the `for(int i = 0; i < cssGM.Count(); i++)` loop. I guess that has something to do with it.